# Broadcast receiver in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, android-broadcast

I use broadcast receiver, and in Fragment.java i register. But it's not working.
My code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.LOGIN");
intent.putExtra("message", obj.getToken());
intent.setAction("com.sunrise.android.LOGIN");
loginView.getContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    informationStudentPresenter = new InformationStudentPresenter(this);
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.LOGIN");
    getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}
 private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "CLGT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("com.sunrise.android.LOGIN")){
            if(!"".equals(findToken())) {
                informationStudentPresenter.getProfileStudent();
                informationStudentPresenter.showToast();
            }
       }
    }
};
```

Could you tell me where my mistake and how to fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're changing the Intent's action name right after initializing it with a different name. Then you're registering the broadcast receiver with an IntentFilter that waits for the old action name.

Comment: Sorry, Your mean is inten.setAction("android.intent.action.LOGIN"); ?

Comment: The string you give to the `Intent`'s constructor is the string you overwriting in `setAction`, is the string you give to `IntentFilter`.

Comment: And the name check in the `onReceive` method is not needed, provided you have the `IntentFilter` expecting the right action name.